# Determine CDF and PDF from quantiles

Tags: density-function, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

I would like to determine CDF and PDF from quantiles that I have determined via quantile regression.
I have read here in the forum ([Find the PDF from quantiles](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347964/find-the-pdf-from-quantiles)) that it is possible to interpolate this via the integral of a B-spline The PDF should then be determined via a normal evaluation.
Unfortunately I did not understand why I have to use the integral of the B-spline, how can I ensure that the CDF is monotonically increasing and how I then get to the derivative (the PDF)? Can someone help me please?

This is how it currently looks for me:

```
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np

x = np.array([ 38.45442808,  45.12051933,  46.85565437,  47.84576924,
        49.50084204,  50.09833301,  51.3717386 ,  54.85307741,
        59.91982266,  63.11786854,  66.90037244,  67.84446378,
        72.96120777,  73.92993279,  81.63075081,  85.42178836,
        90.70554533,  91.2393176 , 110.03872988])

y = np.array([0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85, 0.90, 0.95])

t,c,k = scipy.interpolate.splrep(x, y)
spline = scipy.interpolate.BSpline(t, c, k, extrapolate=False)
d_spline = spline_.derivative()

N = 100
xmin, xmax = x.min(), x.max()
xx = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize =(12, 8))

ax[0].plot(x, y, 'bo', label='Original points')
ax[0].plot(xx, spline(xx), 'r', label='BSpline')

ax[1].plot(xx, d_spline(xx), 'c', label='BSpline')
```

[image]

My approach doesn't really work well unfortunately and I can't find any numerical examples to help me. I am grateful for all comments and remarks!

Thank you!

Comment: "I have read here in the forum that it is possible to interpolate this via the integral of a B-spline The PDF should then be determined via a normal evaluation." Can you provide a link?

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited a link.

Comment: Welcome to CV. The link includes the crucial proviso "with the condition that all B-spline coefficients are nonnegative."  Without suggesting a B-spline is a good solution (I think it's not in general), you can find how to create such splines by searching our site for [monotonic spline](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=monotonic+spline).

Comment: Thank you! I think i find a solution I think I found through your link to a scipy library. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.pchip_interpolate.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for pointing this out. I think I have been able to solve the problem for me.

```
from scipy.interpolate import pchip_interpolate

import numpy as np

x = np.array([ 38.45442808,  45.12051933,  46.85565437,  47.84576924,
        49.50084204,  50.09833301,  51.3717386 ,  54.85307741,
        59.91982266,  63.11786854,  66.90037244,  67.84446378,
        72.96120777,  73.92993279,  81.63075081,  85.42178836,
        90.70554533,  91.2393176 , 110.03872988])

y = np.array([0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.65, 0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85, 0.90, 0.95])

x_observed = x
y_observed = y
x = np.linspace(min(x_observed), max(x_observed), num=100)
y = pchip_interpolate(x_observed, y_observed, x)
y_d = pchip_interpolate(x_observed, y_observed, x, der=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,6))
ax[0].plot(x_observed, y_observed, "o", label="observation")
ax[0].plot(x, y, label="pchip interpolation")
ax[1].plot(x, y_d, label="pchip interpolation derivative")
fig.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you trust your own pdf?

Comment: Continuing the comment by @Nick, that's scarcely a plausible estimate of the pdf.  It arises because *you are not accounting for the estimation errors in the quantiles.*  Any reasonable procedure would do so and as a result would definitely not exhibit such extreme spikes -- it would surely result in a far smoother estimated density.

Comment: @whuber: If I understood it correctly from the comments, then I would have to account for the estimation errors of the quantiles. Unfortunately, I cannot find a procedure for this. Can you help me with this? Are there any approaches that take this into account? Thank you very much.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34894/919 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68238/919 for explanations and examples.